# How do I urlencode this NSString that contains a JSON inside it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ios7

I have the following json string that should be sent to the backend

```
{
    id = "MU_200255802";
    keywords =     (
        Talk,
        games,
        meetup,
        time,
        meet,
        "Time for Another Game"
    );
}
```

So before this JSON I have the java servlet URL something like

```
http://....net/servletName?
```

How should I urlencode the json string and the url because even after trying several options, I keep getting bad url as an error back in the delegate method. What is the right way to do it/

I tried encoding using

```
NSString *urlStringEncoded = [[NSString stringWithString:urlString] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

and also used other encoding formats too.

Comment: What has the URL got to do with the content of the HTTP POST request?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to create json string

```
           NSError *error;
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@"Your object" options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
            NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: The OP already has the JSON string but appears to misunderstand the technology involved (i.e. doesn't know the difference between the URL string and the HTTP POST request content string).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Google Toolbox for Mac`, check it out here, https://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/checkout

There are Classes named `GTMNSString+HTML`,`GTMNSString+XML`,`GTMNSString+URLArguments`, which contains many encoding methods for you.